# csv, python, update line

Tags: python, csv, append

I am looking to update specific lines of a csv as I run through them in a for loop. For example:

line_of_csv = "item1,item2"

for row in csv:
      if action:
           #line of code to write "action occurred"
output:
    (for lines that action occurred: "item1,item2,action occured")
    (for lines that action didn't occur: "item1,item2"

ideally this would remain in the same file and not have to write a second file. I hope this makes sense and any input is greatly apprecaited!

Comment: Do you want to update a specific line number or if the line contains a specific string of text

Answer (score 0):

my.csv

```
col1,col2
item1,item2
item3,item4
item5,item6
item7,item8
item9,item10
```

code

```
import csv

result = []
with open('my.csv', 'rb') as in_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    for line_num, line in enumerate(reader):
        if line_num == 1:
            line = ['modified', 'line']
        result.append(line)

with open('my.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(result)
```